# webservice deployment error in IIS

Tags: .net, web-services

I created a sample webservice which contain default 'HelloWorld' function as 'webmethod'

when tried  to deploy webservice i gave web.config,app_data,app_code,.asmx file and Bin file in IIS  .but i am getting this error

Server Error in '/WebSite1' Application.
Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
Parser Error Message: Unrecognized configuration section 'connectionStrings'
Source Error:
Line 10: 
Line 11:    
Line 12:    
Line 13:    
Line 14:

this is my webconfig file

Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->

    
    
    
        
        
         section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
        
         section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

```
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
        <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
    </customErrors>
    -->
</system.web>
```

Comment: Can you attach your web.config file to the question please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that IIS is trying to use the wrong version of .NET.  In IIS, go to your web site's (or virtual directory's) properties.  Go to the ASP.NET tab, and select version 2.x.

If it's not an option, you may need to run this command from a command window:

```
aspnet_regiis -i
```